# Why am I getting a 500 internal server error when i try to parse an image from Google place photo API?

Tags: android, api, http, google-api

I get a `ResponseCOde` equal to 500 when i try to connect from a `HttpUrlConnection`   :

```
 try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();


            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                Log.d("QueryUtils","connected");
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                Log.d("QueryUtils","input stream is ours");
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error Response Code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
```

note that I can establish the connection successfully from my web browser.. but in my android app, I get a 500 internal server error

Comment: try to log what url you are hitting?

Comment: i did.. this is the url i'm hitting :                                                                                                                 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CmRbAAAAVTCDCQ4cwGvVn-PCbpA4nvNQei41V62GD_8qkJeNBw6Ivx3VeTPpBmanZDPQCV15qgKgId9VF8h9NNG-mGmrlEo8-F_-t0wSBLHARI2KU9UETeRsoZ2vI-lT-li36YLmEhD7Dtf8fLK12UK_MGNZnqNeGhQSdz76UKFtjj7vEWJdMjpzBpJgiw&key=MY_API_KEY

Comment: are you adding an API key at the end of where it asks for an API key? I guess that's the issue?

Comment: of course i'm adding my API key... but i didn't want it to be public here

Comment: i just wanna know..is the problem from the code, or from android studio(needs some kind of authentication or permission)?